# Why derived class cannot be used in place of base class, as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In the following snippet, I have a template function `foo()` that takes a pointer to some object as a template argument.

```
class P {};
class Q : public P {};

P p;
Q q;

template <P*> void foo() {}

void test() {
  foo<&p>();
  foo<&q>();
}
```

According to the documentation, this should work provided that

> For pointers to objects, the template arguments have to designate the address of a complete object with static storage duration and a linkage (either internal or external), or a constant expression that evaluates to the appropriate null pointer or std::nullptr_t value.

Since the object in question must have static storage duration, I define it globally. However, the compiler complains about the second invocation of `foo()`:

```
test.cc:66:7: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'
      foo<&q>();
      ^~~~~~~
test.cc:62:26: note: candidate template ignored: invalid
explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'p'
    template <P* p> void foo() {}
```

I don't understand why is this happening, and why such usage is forbidden?

Comment: this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027154/why-cant-i-downcast-pointer-to-members-in-template-arguments) may offer some insight: *"for a non-type template-parameter of type pointer to object, qualification conversions (4.4) and the array-to-pointer conversion (4.2) are applied"*. Nothing is said about base-class conversions...

Answer (score 6):

> the template arguments have to designate the address of *a complete object* with static storage duration

A base class subobject is not a complete object.